# DataGridView columns no showing TootipText

Tags: c#, windows, forms

DataGridView (Windows Forms) does not show the defined ToolTipText I have written the columns programmatically and I have entered them by the integrated designer the same result only shows one. Checking the List objects of the DataGridView items. Columns the button columns are with the ToolTipText property empty.

[image]

This the code, help and thank you.

```
            #region Definicion columnas texto
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colTipoDoc = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colTipoDoc.Name = "colTipoDoc";
        colTipoDoc.HeaderText = "Tipo de Documento";
        colTipoDoc.ReadOnly = true;
        colTipoDoc.Width = 150;
        dgRecibidos.Columns.Add(colTipoDoc);

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colFolio = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colFolio.Name = "colFolio";
        colFolio.HeaderText = "Folio";
        colFolio.ReadOnly = true;
        colFolio.Width = 100;
        dgRecibidos.Columns.Add(colFolio);

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colFechaEmision = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colFechaEmision.Name = "colFechaEmision";
        colFechaEmision.HeaderText = "Fecha Emisión";
        colFechaEmision.ReadOnly = true;
        colFechaEmision.Width = 100;
        dgRecibidos.Columns.Add(colFechaEmision);

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colEmisor = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colEmisor.Name = "colEmisor";
        colEmisor.HeaderText = "Emisor";
        colEmisor.ReadOnly = true;
        colEmisor.Width = 260;
        dgRecibidos.Columns.Add(colEmisor);

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colMontoExento = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colMontoExento.Name = "colMontoExento";
        colMontoExento.HeaderText = "Monto Exento";
        colMontoExento.ReadOnly = true;
        colMontoExento.Width = 100;
        colMontoExento.DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle
        {
            Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight,
            Format = "C0"
        };
        dgRecibidos.Columns.Add(colMontoExento);

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colMontoNeto = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colMontoNeto.Name = "colMontoNeto";
        colMontoNeto.HeaderText = "Monto Neto";
        colMontoNeto.ReadOnly = true;
        colMontoNeto.Width = 100;
        colMontoNeto.DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle
        {
            Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight,
            Format = "C0"
        };
        dgRecibidos.Columns.Add(colMontoNeto);

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colIva = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colIva.Name = "colIva";
        colIva.HeaderText = "IVA";
        colIva.ReadOnly = true;
        colIva.Width = 100;
        colIva.DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle
        {
            Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight,
            Format = "C0"
        };
        dgRecibidos.Columns.Add(colIva);

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colMontoTotal = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colMontoTotal.Name = "colMontoTotal";
        colMontoTotal.HeaderText = "Monto Total";
        colMontoTotal.ReadOnly = true;
        colMontoTotal.Width = 100;
        colMontoTotal.DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle
        {
            Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight,
            Format = "C0"
        };
        dgRecibidos.Columns.Add(colMontoTotal);

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colFechaRecepcion = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colFechaRecepcion.Name = "colFechaRecepcion";
        colFechaRecepcion.HeaderText = "Fecha Recepción";
        colFechaRecepcion.ReadOnly = true;
        colFechaRecepcion.Width = 100;
        dgRecibidos.Columns.Add(colFechaRecepcion);

        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn colCapturada = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        colCapturada.Name = "colCapturada";
        colCapturada.HeaderText = "Capturada";
        colCapturada.TrueValue = 1;
        colCapturada.FalseValue = 0;
        colCapturada.ReadOnly = true;
        colCapturada.Width = 100;
        dgRecibidos.Columns.Add(colCapturada);

        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn colValidado = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        colValidado.Name = "colValidado";
        colValidado.HeaderText = "Validado";
        colValidado.TrueValue = 1;
        colValidado.FalseValue = 0;
        colValidado.ReadOnly = true;
        colValidado.Width = 100;
        dgRecibidos.Columns.Add(colValidado);

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colXML = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        colXML.Name = "colXML";
        colXML.HeaderText = "XML";
        colXML.ReadOnly = true;
        colXML.Width = 100;
        colXML.Visible = false;
        dgRecibidos.Columns.Add(colXML);
        #endregion

        #region Definición columnas Botones
        // Los botones
        //
        DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn colBtnVerDTE = new DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn();
        colBtnVerDTE.Name = "colBtnVerDTE";
        colBtnVerDTE.Text = "Ver DTE";
        colBtnVerDTE.ToolTipText = "Ver DTE";
        colBtnVerDTE.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        colBtnVerDTE.HeaderText = "Ver DTE";
        colBtnVerDTE.Width = 80;
        dgRecibidos.Columns.Add(colBtnVerDTE);

        DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn colBtnPDF = new DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn();
        colBtnPDF.Name = "colBtnPDF";
        colBtnPDF.Text = "Ver PDF";
        colBtnPDF.ToolTipText = "Visualizar PDF";
        colBtnPDF.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        colBtnPDF.HeaderText = "DTE";
        colBtnPDF.Width = 80;
        dgRecibidos.Columns.Add(colBtnPDF);

        DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn colBtnRespuesta = new DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn();
        colBtnRespuesta.Name = "colBtnRespuesta";
        colBtnRespuesta.Text = "Enviar Respuesta";
        colBtnRespuesta.ToolTipText = "Enviar Respuesta";
        colBtnRespuesta.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        colBtnRespuesta.HeaderText = "Respuesta";
        colBtnRespuesta.Width = 100;
        dgRecibidos.Columns.Add(colBtnRespuesta);

        DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn colBtnVerOC = new DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn();
        colBtnVerOC.Name = "colBtnVerOC";
        colBtnVerOC.Text = "Ver OC";
        colBtnVerOC.ToolTipText = "Ver Orden de compra en Chile Proveedores";
        colBtnVerOC.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        colBtnVerOC.HeaderText = "Ver OC";
        colBtnVerOC.Width = 100;
        dgRecibidos.Columns.Add(colBtnVerOC);
        #endregion
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you do know that setting a ToolTipText on a DGVColumn means the tooltip will appear when you hover the *header*, not the cells?

Comment: Yes, I know!!! If someone can do the test. I think it is a bug of the DataGridView control. You can do the test with the same code.

Sometimes only the TooltipText is displayed on the third button

Comment: I'll give it a try later; I did test with one column and it worked..

Comment: I've just tried with a new DGV in a netframework472 project, full of button columns and they all worked fine https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQv6a.gif

Answer (score 0):

if anyone can try ,

This is my DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn class, but the same goes for the Microsoft DataGridViewButtonColumn base class

```
   public class DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn : DataGridViewButtonColumn
{
    public DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn()
    {
        this.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewDisableButtonCell();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Adapted from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171619.aspx. Double-buffering was added to remove flicker on re-paints.
/// </summary>
public class DataGridViewDisableButtonCell : DataGridViewButtonCell
{
    private bool enabledValue;

    public bool Enabled
    {
        get { return enabledValue; }
        set
        {
            if (enabledValue == value) return;
            enabledValue = value;
            // force the cell to be re-painted
            if (DataGridView != null) DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
        }
    }

    // Override the Clone method so that the Enabled property is copied. 
    public override object Clone()
    {
        var cell = (DataGridViewDisableButtonCell)base.Clone();
        cell.Enabled = Enabled;
        return cell;
    }

    // By default, enable the button cell. 
    public DataGridViewDisableButtonCell()
    {
        enabledValue = true;
    }

    protected override void Paint(
        Graphics graphics,
        Rectangle clipBounds,
        Rectangle cellBounds,
        int rowIndex,
        DataGridViewElementStates elementState,
        object value,
        object formattedValue,
        string errorText,
        DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
        DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
        DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        // The button cell is disabled, so paint the border, background, and disabled button for the cell. 
        if (!enabledValue)
        {
            var currentContext = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;

            using (var myBuffer = currentContext.Allocate(graphics, cellBounds))
            {
                // Draw the cell background, if specified. 
                if ((paintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.Background) == DataGridViewPaintParts.Background)
                {
                    using (var cellBackground = new SolidBrush(cellStyle.BackColor))
                    {
                        myBuffer.Graphics.FillRectangle(cellBackground, cellBounds);
                    }
                }

                // Draw the cell borders, if specified. 
                if ((paintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.Border) == DataGridViewPaintParts.Border)
                {
                    PaintBorder(myBuffer.Graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle);
                }

                // Calculate the area in which to draw the button.
                var buttonArea = cellBounds;
                var buttonAdjustment = BorderWidths(advancedBorderStyle);
                buttonArea.X += buttonAdjustment.X;
                buttonArea.Y += buttonAdjustment.Y;
                buttonArea.Height -= buttonAdjustment.Height;
                buttonArea.Width -= buttonAdjustment.Width;

                // Draw the disabled button.                
                ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(myBuffer.Graphics, buttonArea, PushButtonState.Disabled);

                // Draw the disabled button text.  
                var formattedValueString = FormattedValue as string;
                if (formattedValueString != null)
                {
                    TextRenderer.DrawText(myBuffer.Graphics, formattedValueString, DataGridView.Font, buttonArea, SystemColors.GrayText, TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsTranslateTransform | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
                }

                myBuffer.Render();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // The button cell is enabled, so let the base class handle the painting. 
            base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, elementState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
        }
    }
}
```